# WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies in Jersey Test due to mocked bean

Tags: java, mockito, jax-rs, weld, jersey-test-framework

I am trying to create a mock bean in my controller test. The test fails due to ambiguity, 2 beans with same qualifiers exists.

**Test Code:**

```
public class HelloControllerTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Mock
    private HelperService helperService;

    @InjectMocks
    private GreetingsService greetingsService;

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        return new ResourceConfig(HelloController.class)
                .register(new AbstractBinder() {
                    @Override
                    protected void configure() {
                        bind(helperService).to(HelperService.class);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Test
    public void testHello(){
        String mockResponse = "Hello from mocked helper service!";
        Mockito.when(helperService.hello()).thenReturn(mockResponse);
        String entity = target("/hello").request().get(String.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("Wrong response", mockResponse, entity);
    }
}
```

**Source Code:**

```
@Path("/")
@Produces("application/text")
public class HelloController {

    private final GreetingsService greetingsService;

    @Inject
    public HelloController(GreetingsService greetingsService) {
        this.greetingsService = greetingsService;
    }


    @GET
    @Path("hello")
    public Response hello(){
        return Response.ok(greetingsService.hello()).build();
    }
}


@ApplicationScoped
public class GreetingsService {

    private final HelperService helperService;

    @Inject
    public GreetingsService(HelperService helperService){
        this.helperService = helperService;
    }


    public String hello(){
        return helperService.hello();
    }
}

public class HelperService {

    public String hello(){
        return "Hello from helper service!";
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class HelperServiceProducer {

    @Produces
    public HelperService createHelperService(){
        return new HelperService();
    }
}
```

The test fails with an exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type HelperService with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public example.services.GreetingsService(HelperService)
  at example.services.GreetingsService.<init>(GreetingsService.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - org.glassfish.jersey.inject.cdi.se.bean.InstanceBean@1929425f,
  - Producer Method [HelperService] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces public example.utils.HelperServiceProducer.createHelperService()]
```

The code source can be found at https://github.com/maximkir/study-weld

The question is how to mark the created mock bean as the desired bean for injection? Can I add an `@Alternative` with `@Priority(100)` to the generated mock?

Comment: Remove the producer class or method and you should be fine.

Comment: The producer class is part of source code, I can't just remove it during unit-tests phase.

Comment: From the stacktrace and you saying the producer is from actual source, that means `org.glassfish.jersey.inject.cdi.se.bean.InstanceBean@1929425f` is the other mocked bean, right? That is introduced via CDI extension in some (presumably) jersey-cdi-mockito integration code. This bit of code is where you need to look to figure if they support CDI alternatives in some way. You are thinking along the right lines with alternatives and priority but putting it directly on the field (IMO) won't work.

Comment: As I see the problem is that a Jersey Test framework doesn't provide an option to customize the used class path hence both beans are loaded and Weld throws an exception. As their guide states, on ambiguous dependencies: "There can be only one." I will consider to use Arquillian framework instead.